# ¿Cómo obtener el índice de una matriz a través de un foreach tras haber pasado por un for?

Tags: c#

Los números aleatorios que están de salida en el `for` quisiera encontrar su índice en el `foreach` para luego ordenarlos.

```
for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)                        
{
     array[i] = rnd.Next(numMin, numMax);
     System.Console.WriteLine("Numero [{0}]={1} ", i + 1, array[i]);
}                          
foreach (int j in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine("valor {0}",j );
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no iteras nuevamente con un `for` en lugar de un `foreach`? Estarías obteniendo el índice con la variable `i` o la variable `j`, dependiendo de la definición que le desees dar.

Comment: También podrías usar un `List` para insertar los datos, después ordenar la lista definiendo el orden que quieras, y finalmente si lo que quieres es el resultado en un array puedes usar `lista.ToArray()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que usar dos `Foreach` o dos `For` (anidados). Pudieras usar el ordenamiento de burbuja para organizarlos.

Por ejemplo:

```
/**
 * Sorts array of n values.
 */
void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < i-1; j++)
        {
            int temp = values[j];
            values[j] = values[j+1];
            values[j+1] = temp;
        }       
    }
    //To print the sorted array.
    for (int a=0; a < n; a++)
    {
        printf("%i\t",values[a]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Paul, bienvenido a [es.so] me parece que el OP no hace referencia al ordenamiento, sino, simplemente a obtener el índice al momento de la iteración,